# Is Huygens principle applicable in different mediums?

Tags: optics, refraction, huygens-principle

In the proof of refraction using Huygens principle, once the light hits different medium, it is said the position of light after 't' seconds in 'A' medium and 'B' medium should be on a straight line and the $\angle ABB'=90^{\circ}$.

[image]

But how is it always true that the position of light in different medium stays on a common tangent always. For example, in the following diagram light travels $c_1t$ distance in B medium and $c_2t$ distance in A medium. Clearly they are not in a common tangent.

[image]

> So, my question Is Huygens principle applicable in different mediums?
> If so, then how would you explain the second scenario with it? If not,
> then what is actually going on in the refraction proof?